# z in bash script returns zero

Tags: bash, shell, test

```
#[ -z "" ] 

#echo $?
```

returns 0

```
#[ -a "" ] 

#echo $?
```

returns 1

except z all other alphabets throw 1
What might be the reason?

Comment: Did you try reading the man page? Either `man bash` or `man [` would do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `help test` (with parts omitted for clarity):

```
test: test [expr]
    Evaluate conditional expression. 

    File operators:
      -a FILE        True if file exists.

    String operators:
      -z STRING      True if string is empty.
```

`[ -z "" ]` is clearly true, the string provided is empty. `[ -a "" ]`, however, isn't -- in Unix, zero length filenames are disallowed, so such a filename (or lack thereof) cannot exist.

Comment: Why z is chosen?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that it was chosen by POSIX because it is the first letter of "zero", as in zero-length.

Comment: He he you have wild creativity @Chris

Comment: @ChrisDown, `test` was introduced in Unix V7 released in 1979 (previous versions had an `if` command) and already had `-z`, so that predates POSIX by decades. [The Unix v7 manual for `test`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=test&manpath=Unix%20Seventh%20Edition) says: _-z s1    true if the length of string s1 is zero._

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks. My knowledge of Unix history prior to the late 80s is not good.

Answer (score 3):

`-z` is for `zero` or `zero-length`. The empty string is often called the *null string*. `-n` is *non-null*. In POSIX shells and with a POSIX `[` (aka `test`) command, all of those are equivalent:

1. `[ -z "$var" ] && echo empty`
2. `[ ! -n "$var" ] && echo empty`
3. `[ ! "$var" ] && echo empty`
4. `! [ "$var" ] && echo empty`
5. `[ "$var" = "" ] && echo empty`
6. `[ "${#var}" -eq 0 ] && echo empty`
7. `test -z "$var" && echo empty`
8. `[ "x$var" = x ] && echo empty`
9. ```
   case $var in
     "") echo empty
   esac
   ```

But note that there are (old) implementations of `[` where only 8 works reliably for some values of `$var` like `!` or `=`. `9` works reliable in every Bourne-like shell.